# Java 8 How to return from a method if Optional is not present?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I don't means return a Optional value, I mean for a method:

```
public void someMethod() {
    Optional<Obj> obj = someService.getObj();
    if (obj.isPresent()) {
         ....
    } else {
       log.info(xxxx);
       return;
    }
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    other codes
}
```

Is is possible to write it with Optional.ifPresent way? I mean, avoid to use the if isPresent thing.

Many thanks.

== updated:

it seems ifPresentOrElse in JDK9 can do this, but is there any way to do this in JAVA8?

I don't need this method return any value, but if the Optional not present, I want to log something.

Comment: If you want to return if the Optional isn't present, the if/else statement looks good to me. Can't think why you'd want or need to do it another way

Comment: Just learning and researching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a use case for `ifPresentOrElse` as in Java-9 :

```
obj.ifPresentOrElse(a -> {...}, () -> {logger.info(xxxx);return; });
```

Comment: Good solution. The `return;` inside the lambda doesn’t do what you think.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's not of much use agreed. But not sure what in the current context is the use of `return` as well!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do nothing when the `Optional` is empty, you can use `ifPresent`:

```
public void someMethod() {
    someService.getObj().ifPresent (v -> {
         ....
    });   
}
```

Comment: However you can't return the obj, because ifPresent is void method, you can only do something with your object. To return value, use if (obj.isPresent())

Comment: @TaaviKivimaa based on the void method the OP posted, I assumed there's no need to return anything.

Comment: OP's english got me confused there, thought he was trying to return something inside the if statement and set a bad example code with void method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I don't need to return any value, but I want to log something if not present.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing an idea out there, what about having a method on the service to check if the object is present? 
I think that generally you don't want to spread your Optionals all over your code, I'd prefer to keep it inside the service.

On `SomeService`:

```
public boolean isObjectPresent() {
    return getObj().isPresent();
}
```

Then

```
public void someMethod() {
    if (someService.isObjectPresent()) {
         ....
    } else {
       log.info(xxxx);
       return;
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with the `Optional` in your call as you don't really care about its value

NOTE: Also, I'd add that if you have no code after the if blocks, you don't need the return statement.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. This is just an example, I have more codes after the if. so I must return if not present. sorry I didn't mention that, I adjusted my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Optional.ofNullable(input).orElseGet(this::methodName);

If the input is null then it goes to orElseGet logic. If input is not null then return the input value.

Please refer to section 'Difference Between orElse and orElseGet()' of https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional