# Optional and complete method

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

How to work correctly with Optional if I need to complete a method (with some actions, log for example) in case of an empty Optional? Otherwise, get the object from Optional and continue working

I found similar problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393419/1460643
But there **return** is used in lambda

My code,

```
...
    var productOptional = productVersionMongoService.findById(crmProductId)
        .map(ProductVersion::getProductId)
        .flatMap(productMongoService::findById);
    Product product;
    if (productOptional.isEmpty()) {
      log.warn(...);
      return Collections.emptySet();
    } else {
      product = productOptional.get();
    }
...
```

So my question is, is it possible to refactor it to make the code more attractive?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Fne except the `else` clause is useless.  Without it, the `if ()` is a proper guard clause, which is good style because it eliminates nesting. Then you can move the declaration for `product` down to the assignment.

Comment: Using good old `null` is not bad, as long as it obvious to readers of the code that it may occur and will be handled correctly. For example: `var product = productVersionMongoService.findById(crmProductId) .map(ProductVersion::getProductId) .flatMap(productMongoService::findById) .orElse(null); if(product == null) { log.warn(...); return Collections.emptySet(); } /* proceed with using product */` Note how `.orElse(null)` is immediately followed by `if(product == null)`…

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this, although it isn't completely clear from your question what gets returned in the case that a `Product` is found.:

```
Collection<Product> find(String crmProductId) {
        var productOptional = productVersionMongoService.findById(crmProductId)
                                       .map(ProductVersion::getProductId)
                                       .flatMap(productMongoService::findById);
        return productOptional.map(p -> {
            // ...
            return Collections.singleton(p);
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
            log.warn();
            return Collections.emptySet();
        });
    }
```

Comment: If the product is found... Information about it is being collected. For good reason, if there is no product, then there must be an error, but in business this is not possible